# Marionette/backbone app, href in a tag doesn't go to defined route

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Here is my A tag in index.html.

```
<div class="menu-item"><a href="/#login">Login in</a>
```

If I click it, it should go to '/login' route. But URL correctly changed to localhost:3333/#login in browser address input bar, but the page content shows no change, still in landing page.

Here is my code for starting Backbone history:

```
new Router();
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/'});
```

Here is my code for router:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
    Backbone.$ = $;
var _ = require('lodash');

var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
var OuterLayout = require('../layout/outerLayout/outerLayout');
var ol = new OuterLayout();
var AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    routes : {
        '': 'index',
        'signup' : 'signup', 
        'login' : 'login'
    }, 
    index : function () {
        if(_.isEmpty(ol.el.innerHTML)) {
            ol.render();
        } 

        // outerLayout.footer.show();    
    }, 
    signup : function () {
        if(_.isEmpty(ol.el.innerHTML)) {
            ol.render();
        }
        var ContentSignup = require('../layout/outerLayout/view/contentSignup/contentSignup');

        ol.content.show(new ContentSignup());
    }, 
    login: function () {
        if(_.isEmpty(ol.el.innerHTML)) {
            ol.render();
        }
        var ContentLogin = require('../layout/outerLayout/view/contentLogin/contentLogin');

        ol.content.show(new ContentLogin());
    }    
});

module.exports = AppRouter;
```

The result is that URL changed in the browser address input field, but the page content doesn't change. Then if I hit CMD + R to refresh the page, then the content will change, correctly reflecting the route.

Also the go back button on browser doesn't work, url changes, but the content doesn't change. I think I forget to call sth in my code to "refresh" the browser?

oh, I am using [httpster](http://simbco.github.io/httpster/) to start a mini http server for this front-end development.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
new AppRouter();
```

instead of this

```
new Router();
```

Comment: I tried it. The result is "Cannot GET /login". Look like router cannot resolve the route if I remove the #. Is there anything I should config before removing #?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually want to hit the server (which would just be `/login` and you'd deal with it on the server side). You should take the pub sub approach.

So in your view you would say:

triggers
  "click .menu-item": "loginClicked"

Then in your controller you can listen to that event (if it's a composite view's childview that you're in you may have to prefix this with `childview:`):

```
@listenTo loginView, "login:button:clicked", (args) ->
  App.vent.trigger "login:clicked"
```

Then in the router

```
API =
    login: ->
      new LoginsApp.Show.Controller

  App.vent.on "login:clicked", ->
    App.navigate "/login" 
    API.login()
```

So you end up navigating/hitting the same action that you would by going through the router, but you don't have to rely on the routes.

If you don't want to go that route I imagine the problem is that you need to say `Backbone.history.navigate({trigger: true})` to get it to actually trigger the route in the approuter.

The best approach I've found is the approuter is there when the user clicks refresh or navigates directly to the page. But everything else should be handled in app with the pub sub approach. It gives you the most control that way.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash (/) and use only "#route" on your hrefs, to avoid the browser from fetching the default document served at "/" from the backend.

By the way, watch your use of require, you should require the constructors at the top so the requirejs optimizer can fill in the dependencies on build time.

Something like:

```
//this before the component definition
var MyView = require("views/myview"),
    AppLayout = require("views/layout");

//... later on your view/app/model definition

function foo(){
  var view = new MyView();
}
```

I also think having a list of `require`d stuff at the top of any file helps understanding it later on. ;)